# What are the best practices when one needs to store [enough] large amount of plaintext files?

Tags: database, database-design

Assume one has 100K+ plaintext files. With each file there is some structured information associated. Files are likely to be retrieved by describing that properties. That is, I have a file `important_file` and an array with (mandatory) values filled in: `{property0: value0, ..., propertyN: valueN}`. Each of that field is filled before the file is added to collection, so at every moment thereafter I can describe that file with that values.

The question is: is it better to store files within DB (size is guaranteed to be <=5MB (most probable size is ~500KB in 99% cases)) or directly in FS? Should I look at document-oriented (like MongoDB) solution in case the answer is "DB"?

Links to similar cases are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle, storing files outside database has no benefits, [according to Tom Kyte](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1011065100346196442).

I suspect other modern DBMSes behave similarly. Even if some of them doesn't, consider very carefully whether it's worth trading the data integrity (guaranteed by the database) for performance...

Comment: Did you mean that storing files in FS gives more performance than storing them in DB? Is it true for all DB's?

Comment: @cdshines I _may_ in some cases on certain DBMSes. However I'd advise against it unless you have judiciously benchmarked it and concluded you absolutely can't live without the extra performance. OTOH, there may be cases where filesystem is actually _slower_.

Comment: No, it's my pet project and I'm on stage of designing architecture now, so there aren't performance issues as for now, neither do I expect those to come into being. By the way, does MongoDB's GridFS seem appropriate for this task?

Comment: @cdshines Sorry, I'm not familiar with no-SQL databases.